# how to wirte a javascript code which check each element

Tags: javascript

my problem is a table with multiple  tag, some of the has text "hide",for exampe: hide, i want to add a javascript code , it will be check each  element, and if it has text hide, add this attribute [ display:none ], can someone help me out writting this in the best way?
i dont know how to use the codes:

> .each() & .html() & .text()

is it possible to this with jquery?

for example you can see this structure:

```
 <tr class="header">
  <td colspan="9">Header 1</td>
```

```
         <td>lorem ipsum</td>
             <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>hide</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="filter">
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>hide</td>
      <td>hide</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="9">Header 2</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Please show us evidence that you have _tried_ to do some javascript work on this project.

Comment: `$("table *").each(function(){if($(this).text() == "hide")$(this).hide()});`

Comment: It's not clear which one do you want to hide. Your example doesn't contain any "hide" :/

Comment: sorry, it gets correct?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery it’s easy:

```
$('td:contains(hide)').hide();
```

Comment: is it necessary to put it in a loop such a .each() ?

Comment: @user2629842 not in code, jQuery loops through the collection internally.

Answer (score 1):

Use (with jQuery):

```
$("table td, table th").filter(function () { return $(this).text() == "hide"; }).hide();
```

Comment: if i want to check both td and th elements, how should i rewrite that?

Comment: `$("table th, table td")`